# Причина неотработки js-скрипта

Tags: javascript, drupal, switch

Здравствуйте.

1. Есть тема для Друпал 7 - `Media Responsive Theme`, в которой есть папка js, в ней лежат три скрипта темы.
2. Eсть свой js-скрипт `moiscript.js` для кнопки переключения темы.
3. js-скрипт положен в папку js темы, в файле `.info` темы прописана строка  `scripts[] = js/moiscript.js` (сразу после таких же строк, относящихся к тем трём js-скриптам темы, которые идут по умолчанию).
4. Содержимое файла `moiscript.js:`

```js
$('.span img[src=/путь_к_картинке_для_переключения_тем]').click(function(event) {
    $('#block-switchtheme-switch-form #edit-theme').val('название_темы');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#block-switchtheme-switch-form .form-submit').click();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

5. Запускаю `update.php` для обновления `бд`, сбрасываю `кэш` сайта.
   но ничего не работает.
6. Пробую вставить свой код в один из js-скриптов темы - тот же результат.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста! Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала напиши там просто

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

У тебе скрипт  не работает с друпалом все хорошо.

Или еще вариант что тема другая работает, проверь это.
Для этого включи theme_debug то есть пропиши в settings.php

```
$cong['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

в разметке появяться коментарии с указанием шаблоно которые используються,тогда и поймеш какая тема работает точно.

Еще возможен вариант что в `html.tpl.php` просто кто то удалил переменную `$scripts`

можешь проверить чем твоя тема отличаеться от темы оригинала, есть подозреие что кто криворукий ее трогал :)
поставь эту тему чистую, у меня она работает отлично, потом в ней проверишь скрипты

Comment: спасибо за ответ! тема работает 100% эта, она по умолчанию. не могу понять, работают ли вообще скрипты самой темы. в консоли есть инфа только про отработку скриптов из папки /sites/default/files/js, а про скрипты самой темы нет ничего вообще. такое может теоретически быть? и если да то куда его тогда прописывать?

Comment: дописал в скрипт самой темы
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('ready!');
  }); - ничего нет( значит, скрипты темы не работают почему-то?

Comment: видно реально кто-то до меня направил тему, не работает в ней ничего. а вот если прилепить скрипт в отдельный блок вроде как что-то происходит. ну и да, добавил к скрипту вначале $( document ).ready(function() { и в конце }); - без этого ничего вообще не происходило текст отображался... спаибо!

Comment: зы а переменная скриптс на месте, кстати